# Consuming Restful API in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, django-rest-framework, ember-data

I've gone through the Ember JS tutorial twice and I feel like I'm pretty confident with it now, however the only thing the tutorial (Super Rental) never covered, was how to properly fetch data from an external API service, and then display that information on the page, for editing and for saving back to the API server.

Are there any tutorials out there that cover this, even example projects would be a big help.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `ember-data` and a `rest serializer` or just use `ajax` calls in your routes. [Ember screencasts](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/) - (https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/108-ember-data-20-overview-of-using-adapters-and-serializers) and [Ember Igniter](https://emberigniter.com) are good resources for all things ember.

Comment: @Craicerjack - Thank you for these resources, as I'm just starting out with Ember these are going to be invaluable.